# How can I return to main in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been working on a project recently which is a simple game. I've written the following code in my main function (file main.cpp):

```
    ending_note = "Draw.";
    End_Page end(ending_note, a);
    end.show();
    (*a).exec();
    if(end.flag == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    } //end if
```

where a is a Qapplication object. The class End_Page is defined as follows (file end_page.cpp):

```
End_Page::End_Page(string _winner, QApplication* _a, QWidget *parent):QWidget(parent){

a = _a;
this->setFixedSize(900, 675);
this->move(350, 50);
flag = 0;

//------------------- background label
background = new QLabel(this);
QMovie* movie2 = new QMovie("..\\project\\Data\\pic\\7.jpeg");
movie2->setScaledSize(QSize(this->width(), 600));
background->setMovie(movie2);
background->setGeometry(0, 0, this->width(), 600);
movie2->start();

//-------------------- set label
QString s;
label = new QLabel(s.fromStdString(_winner), this);
label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : rgb(200, 0, 30); qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter; }");
QFont f( "MV Boli", 32, QFont::Bold);
label->setFont(f);
label->setGeometry(0,this->height() - 400, this->width(), 160);

question = new QLabel("Do you want to play again?\n", this);
question->setStyleSheet("QLabel { color : black;}");
question->setGeometry(375, 610, 200, 30);

accept = new QPushButton("Yes", this);
accept->setGeometry(300, 630, 80, 40);
decline = new QPushButton("No", this);
decline->setGeometry(500, 630, 80, 40);

//-------------------- connect
connect(this,SIGNAL(closeSignal()), this, SLOT(closeProgram()));
connect(decline, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(closeProgram()));
connect(accept, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(restartProgram()));
```

}

```
End_Page::~End_Page(){}

void End_Page::closeEvent(QCloseEvent* event){
emit closeSignal();
event->accept();
```

}

```
void End_Page::EndGame(){
a->exit();
```

}

```
void End_Page::closeProgram(){
exit(0);
```

}

```
void End_Page::restartProgram(){
flag = 1;
a->exit();
```

}

My problem is that, after the program executes the statement (*a).exec();, if the user click on the push button labeled Yes, the program executes the function restartProgram to the end, but after that it doesn't continue back in function main (in other words it gets stuck there). How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `quit()` or `exit()` as static class members (you don't need to pass your `QApplication` around):

> For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows at any given time. For non-GUI Qt applications, use QCoreApplication instead, as it does not depend on the QtGui library.
>   The QApplication object is accessible through the instance() function that returns a pointer equivalent to the global qApp pointer.

```
void End_Page::restartProgram(){
    flag = 1;
    QApplication::quit();  
}
```

But, the main problem in your application is that you are emmiting `closeSignal()` in your `closeEvent()` and the slot connected to it will call `exit(0);` system call, which is, I think, completely unnecessary, and which will "kill" the current process.

Here is a completely working example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <qtimer>
#include <iostream>

/* Move this into h file and moc it! */
class Window:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void closeApp(){ QApplication::quit(); flag = 500; }
public:
    int flag;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window win;
    QTimer::singleShot(5000, &win, SLOT(closeApp()));
    a.exec();

    std::cout << "Flag: " << win.flag << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

Why are you doing this:

```
if(end.flag == 1) // flag is set to 1 in restartProgram slot
{
    return 1; 
} //end if
```

This will exit your `main()` function, and it will not restart program.

Comment: As you said, I removed the part emit closeSignal(), but the program still don't work properly. You know, I don't want the program to close, I want it just to simply make the flag equal to 1, and then execute the rest of the caller function, but still it seems to get stuck when it performs the function restartProgram().

Comment: @GoodarzMehr What do you mean by "stuck"? Attach debugger there and try to go step by step. See my edit, I may found what is wrong...

Comment: Well, I mean when I put printf("%d\n, 1) after the statement flag = 1; each time yes is clicked, 1 is printed, but nothing else is done, and the program won't execute the if statement after (*a).exec() in the program. Actually, that if statement is not in the main function, it's in another function called by main. but still, my problem is that the program don't even reach that statement to execute it.

Comment: Even better, attach debugger on line after `(*a).exec();`.

Comment: @GoodarzMehr does the application exits, or does not response anymore? Are you starting it from a command line, so you can see all output? Problem is not in this part of code. I suggest you use debugger, set breakpoints on few points, and run the program. I've replicated your setup and it seems to be working properly.